# Books to learn about how a car works, in a well structured manner

Tags: automotive-design

Lets assume that I want to build a custom vehicle using spare parts lying around in a mechanic shop.
I don't know squat about how cars work.

What books do you suggest I read in order to understand the powertrain, body, electronics and other parts of the car, in the right sequence, in order to understand the way cars work enough to carry out my task?

Comment: Start with motor venicle technology by Hillier & Pittuck

Comment: You could find a community college, or any college with automotive, and see if you can buy a graduates curriculum when they graduate. You may have to wait this next semester out unless you may know of someone who has already completed a program.